# Getting historic App versions from App Store API

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there any way of getting more than just the latest version of your App on the App Store?

I have found [this endpoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_app_store_versions_for_an_app) from appstoreconnectapi but it only gives me the latest one. Is there really no historic data or am I holding it wrong?